# What is the correct way to connect to a database from an eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, datasource, eclipse-rap

I am evaluating the Rich Ajax Platform (RAP) and I need to connect to a DB2 database (and perhaps others).

Having done a fair amount of J2EE work I usually fetch a DataStore object via JNDI and use that to connect to a database. The actual connection parameters are configured outside of the application and can be adapted for development, test and production environments.

-- How should I go about this from within a plugin in RAP?

-- What is the best way to handle connections in different enviroments?

-- I also don't want to include the DB2 JDBC jars in the plugin as they may differ slightly between development and production.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://www.eclipse.org/datatools